# running a list through a function

Tags: python

I have defined a function which compares a point to two different points and return `True` if a couple of `if` conditions are met.

I now want the function to accept a list of 3 inputs, instead of a single input and return `True` only if all three inputs in the list meet my `if` conditions.

I can't figure out how to change my code to achieve this.

disclaimer: I'm a complete newbie to python. I have only been doing this for 2 weeks. go easy on me :)

```
#code #1 to allow one input for "point"

def isIn(firstCorner=(0,0), secondCorner=(0,0), point=(0,0)):
    if (firstCorner[0] >= point[0] >=  secondCorner[0] ) and (firstCorner[1] >= point[1] >=  secondCorner[1] ):
            print(True)
    elif (secondCorner[0] >= point[0] >=  firstCorner[0] ) and (secondCorner[1] >= point[1] >=  firstCorner[1] ):
            print(True)
    elif (firstCorner[0] >= point[0] >=  secondCorner[0] ) and (firstCorner[1] <= point[1] <=  secondCorner[1] ):
            print(True)
    elif (secondCorner[0] >= point[0] >=  firstCorner[0] ) and (secondCorner[1] <= point[1] <=  firstCorner[1] ):
            print(True)
    else: 
        print(False)

#inputs to test if my code works

isIn((70,2), (60,45), (60,4)) 
isIn((999,645), (2345,100), (1100,101))


#code #2 to allow list of inputs under "pointList". this is definetly wrong and i can't figure out what i need to do to make this work

def allIn(firstCorner=(0,0), secondCorner=(0,0), pointList=[]):
    for x in allIn(pointList):
        if (firstCorner[0] >= pointList[0]>=  secondCorner[0] ) and (firstCorner[1] >= pointList[1] >=  secondCorner[1] ):
            print(True)
        elif (secondCorner[0] >= pointList[0] >=  firstCorner[0] ) and (secondCorner[1] >= pointList[1] >=  firstCorner[1] ):
             print(True)
        elif (firstCorner[0] >= pointList[0] >=  secondCorner[0] ) and (firstCorner[1] <= pointList[1] <=  secondCorner[1] ):
            print(True)
        elif (secondCorner[0] >= pointList[0] >=  firstCorner[0] ) and (secondCorner[1] <= pointList[1] <=  firstCorner[1] ):
             print(True)
        else: 
            print(False)

#inputs to test code above

allIn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,5)])
```

I want to change code number one to be able to allow a list of 2 coordinates/inputs instead of a single 2 coordinates/inputs. All "if" conditions should be the same and return `True` only if all inputs in list meet the condition. Return `False` even if one set of coordinates in the list don't meet the conditions

Comment: @Tomothy32
code #2 is my attempt. i tried using "for x in" function but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if im using this incorrectly. 

I'm not asking anyone to do it for me. i'm just not sure if my use of the function is incorrect or if there's an alternative i should be using than the "for x in" function.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your attempt the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your function takes two points that define an area (they are opposite corner of an area that has sides parallel to the axes of the system) and a third point and it returns whether the point falls inside the area.

You're looking to make the function so that, instead of taking a single point, it takes a list and checks if *all* of the points in the list fall in the area.

First of all, there are a lot of library functions out there that do just this and more, so perhaps you should look at using those if this has serious applications. Especially if you need to check more complicated areas later.

However, to do what you want to do, a very clean approach would be to have a function that checks for one point and then write a second function that calls the first for all items in a list.

Like this:

```
def is_in(corner1, corner2, point):
    min_x, max_x = sorted([corner1[0], corner2[0]])
    min_y, max_y = sorted([corner1[1], corner2[1]])
    return (min_x <= point[0] <= max_x) and (min_y <= point[1] <= max_y)


def all_in(corner1, corner2, points):
    return all(is_in(corner1, corner2, p) for p in points)


print(all_in((0, 0), (5, 5), [(1, 1), (0, 0), (5, 5)]))
```

I've take the liberty of rewriting your `isIn` function as well (and renaming it `is_in` because that is more in line with Python naming conventions).

It works by first working out what values to compare to and then just returns the result of the entire comparison in one go.

To answer your actual question about your code:

- you call the function itself on the first line, which is a problem.
- and although you appear to want to loop over the list with x, you're not comparing x to the corners

Your code, fixed:

```
def allIn(firstCorner, secondCorner, pointList):
    for x in pointList:
        if (firstCorner[0] >= x[0] >= secondCorner[0]) and (firstCorner[1] >= x[1] >= secondCorner[1]):
            print(True)
        elif (secondCorner[0] >= x[0] >= firstCorner[0]) and (secondCorner[1] >= x[1] >= firstCorner[1]):
            print(True)
        elif (firstCorner[0] >= x[0] >= secondCorner[0]) and (firstCorner[1] <= x[1] <= secondCorner[1]):
            print(True)
        elif (secondCorner[0] >= x[0] >= firstCorner[0]) and (secondCorner[1] <= x[1] <= firstCorner[1]):
            print(True)
        else:
            print(False)
```

You're also assuming the corners are ordered in a specific way though, which isn't very intuitive. And your function doesn't collect a result, it just prints whether the individual points are in the list.

With my example, to do that:

```
def print_all_in(corner1, corner2, points):
    for p in points:
        print(is_in(corner1, corner2, p))
```

An inefficiency in my code is that the points get sorted every time - you could sort them first and then use a more efficient function still to just check for all of the points - but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: You can use `all(is_in(corner1, corner2, p) for p in points)` to short-circuit.